# Unable to deploy Qt 5.3 Quick application to AVD under Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: qt, osx-mavericks, android-virtual-device

I have spent dozens of time looking for the solution. I gave up.

I use Qt 5.3 for development and I build cross platform solution.

My MacbBook Pro runs Mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks.

My project successfully runs in ios-simulator and desktop builds. 
But I couldn't deploy it to neither AVD nor real Android Device.

Here is the logs:

```
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /Users/xxx/build-xxx-Android_for_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-libxxx.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /Users/xxx/build-xxx-Android_for_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-build
  Application binary: /Users/xxx/build-xxx-Android_for_armeabi_v7a-Debug/libxxx.so
  Android build platform: android-19
  Install to device: emulator-5554
19:43:56: The process "/Applications/Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project xxx (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Deploy to Android device'
19:43:56: Elapsed time: 02:13.
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Since you're deploying to a device, have you configured any devices within Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The issue was:
I set incorrect path to ant executable.
Qt was not able to build android app and for sure deploy it.

Now I am able to run app on the device, but still can't run app with emulator.

Good luck.